# REST: 404 Not found

Tags: services, 8

I strictly followed [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2424977) guide. The REST Server is activated. I try to access `http://localhost/rest/user/token.json` (the Drupal installation is at `localhost`) via the Firefox REST Easy Add-On. No success. It always gives me a "404 Not Found" error.

Under the "Resources" Tab of the Service Module configuration, all resources are enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you flush all caches?

Comment: Yes. Did not help.

Comment: What HTTP method are you using? You should be using POST to access ?q=[endpoint]/user/token.json. Alternatively, you can use GET on ?q=services/session/token.

Comment: I am using `POST`. The request with the query works well, however, the URL that I provided above doesn't.